# Preposition: Oldest town in/of England

Tags: prepositions, exam-questions, in-of

> London is the oldest town **of / in** England.

Which is the correct preposition to use here ? My book says *In* but why *of* is wrong here ? Reading the sentence both sound correct.

Comment: To a native speaker, only *in* will sound correct. Technically speaking, it's not ungrammatical to use *of*, but nobody really uses it and it sounds strange to use in that context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> London is the oldest town **in** England.

is correct since the town's location is within England.

> town **of** England.

might be understood to mean a town full of England, which is not possible since England is much bigger than a town, or they might think you are saying "*town of English*" in the same way that

> a bucket **of** water

is a bucket full of water.

The other error in your sentence is *factual*

> **Colchester** is the oldest town in England.

Comment: No one would hear "town of England" by analogy with "bucket of water".